# MongoDB Query with a Tuple

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document structure:

```
{
  Foo: BinData
  Bar: Integer
}
```

I want to search these documents (they have other fields) by the two fields Foo and Bar (they together make up a key to search for).

I am currently doing this:

```
List<Tuple<byte[], int>> fooBarList = mySearchValues;
return Collection.AsQueryable().OfType<MyType>()
                .Where(x => fooBarList.Any(y => x.Foo == y.Item1 && x.Bar == y.Item2))
                .ToArray();
```

However Mongo does not understand how to serialize this query.

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Byte[],System.Int32]].
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.GetSerializationInfo(Expression node, Dictionary`2 serializationInfoCache)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildAnyQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildMethodCallQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildQuery(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildQuery(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.SelectQuery.Execute()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Has someone already got a similar query to this, if so how I can do it? I cannot use $in, as this only operates on a single document field.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the driver (1.x) is built for .NET 3.5 and doesn't natively know about how to serialize tuples. If you'd like, you can write a tuple serializer and register it making it such that this query might work.

However, I'd imagine it'd just be easier to not use a Tuple and instead create a simple private class and use that instead.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your help. Using a private class, or an anonymous class does not fix this. It just gives the same error, but with a different class name.Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: Temp[]:{ Namespace+Temp }.

Comment: Can you tell me what the mongodb query should look like?

Comment: The query should look for documents that both Foo and Bar match the query data list (of Foo and Bar pairs). There is a C# example of what I would expect this should look like above.

Comment: Yeah, I see the C# example, but I'm not sure that (after looking a little closer) what you are putting in that query is possible in MongoDB. Can you provide the query you'd like in mongodb query language and I'll help you convert it to C#?